# Windows 10: Hyper-V can't connect to localhost

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

For an internship I would like to use Linux. The only real option I am given is to use Hyper-V to run a virtual Linux machine. I`ve managed to get Hyper-V Manager running by turning all Hyper-V features on under " Turn Windows features on or off".

Unfortunately, when I open Hyper-V Manager open "Connect to Server", select "Local computer" and press "OK". I get the following error message:

> An error occurred while attempting to connect to server "pc-name".
>   Check that the Virtual Machine Management service is running and that
>   you are authorized to connect to the server.
>
> Hyper-V encountered an error trying to access an object on computer
>   "pc-name" because the object was not found. The object might have been
>   deleted. Verify that the Virtual Machine Management service on the
>   computer is running.

On this Windows 10 PC (Dell Latitude E7270) I have been given superuser rights and can run programs as admin, which is done. Furthermore, Virtual Machine Management service is running -- looking at "Services". Can we infer that I am somehow not authorized to connect to the server? If so, how come?

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Either check if the service "Virtual Machine Management service" is running. If that is running then you are not part of the hyper-v administrator group.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Comment: The IT-services people spend some time working on it and gave me an Hyper-V update... So unfortunately I could not tell you what the problem was. Anyway, it has been solved. Thank you.

Comment: I can't comment on another one's answer, but I just wanted to point out that the service referenced by *Dylan* is named "Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management" on my machine. If it helps to find it.

Answer (score 15):

MOFCOMP %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsVirtualization.V2.mof

Comment: Steve: please explain how this helpful, for others unfamiliar.

Comment: I am not familiar with mofcomp, but given that it is a Windows executable and the .mof file mentioned is a Windows file, I decided to trust this and run it. Worked perfectly to restore my missing VM access. Googling for "WindowsVirtualization.V2.mof" shows this as a common answer for connectivity problems. Seems to occur after some system firmware updates.

Comment: This finally worked for me. And I tried Martin's fix above as well as restarting my computer and also attempting to restart the "Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management" service. Huge relief; thanks @steve!

Answer (score 7):

I got this from Dan Hoeger on this thread.. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0a29c671-b640-4c2d-954f-622b25f65ad9/hyperv-encountered-an-error-trying-to-access-an-object-on-computer-object-was-not-found?forum=win10itprovirt

```
Open "Windows Security"
Open "App & Browser control"
Click "Exploit protection settings" at the bottom
Switch to "Program settings" tab
Locate "C:\WINDOWS\System32\vmcompute.exe" in the list and expand it
Click "Edit"
Scroll down to "Control flow guard (CFG)" and uncheck "Override system settings"
Start vmcompute from powershell "net start vmcompute"
```

Hyper-V manager can now connect to my local server.

Answer (score 2):

If you could please clarify, what do you mean when you say you have been given "supersuser rights?"  Which local security groups are you in?

The bottom line is that to utilize Hyper-V on a Windows 10 workstation, your login needs to be a member of the local `Administrators` group and/or the local `Hyper-V Administrators` group.